# Ordering arrays based on a string?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I need to re-order. It is an array of country codes:

```
$countries = array('uk', 'fr', 'es', 'de', 'it');
```

I need to sort the array with a particular user selected country first, ie. 'fr' and the remaining items need to be in alpabetical order.

I am not too sure how to do this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$countries = array('uk', 'fr', 'es', 'de', 'it');
// find and remove user value
$uservar = 'uk';
$userkey = array_search($uservar, $countries);
unset($countries[$userkey]);
// sort ascending
sort($countries,SORT_ASC);
// preappend user value
array_unshift($countries, $uservar);
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it will probably save a μs if you first unset the value, then sort it, and then prepend it, because then there is less to sort. :-)

Comment: @YMMD your probably right !!!! updated my order !!!! *Optimised for performance* now

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit long, but should work.

```
<?php
   $user_selected = 'fr';

   $countries = array('uk', 'fr', 'es', 'de', 'it');
   unset($countries[ array_search($user_selected, $countries) ]); // remove user selected from the list
   sort($countries); // sort the rest

   array_unshift($countries, $user_selected); // put the user selected at the beginning

   print_r($countries);
?>
```

Comment: Your "unset" is wrong. `$user_selected` is the value, not the key. Otherwise, good solution (the algorithm is sane overall).

Answer (score 0):

```
// The option the user selected
$userSelectedOption = 'fr';

// Remove the user selected option from the array
array_splice($countryCodes, array_search($userSelectedOption, $countryCodes), 1);

// Sort the remaining items
sort($countryCodes, SORT_ASC);

// Add the user selected option back to the beginning
array_unshift($countryCodes, $userSelectedOption);
```